# integration user profile

Tags: integration

I am trying to create this profile due to misuse of profiles.

They will be communicating with salesforce through the api. Can I create this profile without giving them the modify all data permission? will it affect integration if this is not included in their profile?

Answer (score 1):

Integration user profile should not have System Admin kind of access. You should clone `Standard User` profile and gradually add necessary permissions which is required.

So, in the profile, you should have `API only user` checked and only provide permission which is needed for that user.

`Modify All` supersedes all the access rights and data visibility requirements which is not encouraged.

Answer (score 1):

An integration user is the same as normal user. They're allowed to do whatever their profile and the sharing model says they can do. Do they need to be able to read all accounts? Then just give them Read access. Do they need to edit accounts? You can create sharing rules for those users (if necessary). The only real suggestion here is to make sure that they are "API only" users to limit the ability to log in, and build their profile very specifically to the task(s) they need to perform. Give them only the field and object access they need.